# Template type deduction failing

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming

I'm using MSVC 9.0 and have this function:

```
class RecipientList
{
public:
    template<class T>
    void fillMessageWithRecipients( typename boost::is_base_of<MsgContent, T>::type* msg );
};

template< class T >
void RecipientList::fillMessageWithRecipients( typename boost::is_base_of<MsgContent, T>::type* msg )
{
 // do stuff
}
```

I want template type deduction to work here, so I can use it like this:

```
class SomeMsg : public MsgContent {};

std::auto_ptr<SomeMsg> msg( new SomeMsg );

RecipientList recipients;
recipients.fillMessageWithRecipients( msg.get() );
```

However I get the compiler error:

> error C2783: 'void
>   RecipientList::fillMessageWithRecipients(boost::is_base_of::type
>   *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'

I have a feeling this has something to do with the fact that the type actually being passed in is a pointer type, and not the type by itself. Any idea how I can properly get type deduction working here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obligatory comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated for several good reasons. You might want to look at [Boost.SmartPointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm)

Comment: C++11 offers smartpointres, too. [See Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers). No need for boost here.

Comment: @pmr From your link: "These templates are designed to complement the std::auto_ptr template.", there is no replacement for auto_ptr outside of moving to C++11 (which I can't do, I'd much prefer to use `unique_ptr` there).

Comment: @RobertDailey `boost::scoped_ptr` is `unique_ptr` without move semantics. Looks appropriate here.

Comment: @pmr My example is contrived for simplicity. In my real code I actually require move semantics. I'm fully aware of other smart pointer choices though.

Comment: @pmr also, since when has auto_ptr been deprecated? C++11 perhaps?

Comment: @RobertDailey C++11. It has been decided that the new smart pointers are sufficient alternatives and that `auto_ptrS` semantics where design mistakes that solved no real problem and caused only problems.

Comment: @pmr Thanks, that's what I suspected. Unfortunately I'm locked into C++03 for now. I've been craving unique_ptr for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling you are misusing `boost::is_base_of`. The nested `type` will be either `true_type` or `false_type`. Neither of those two make sense to take as an argument and your pointers will not be convertible to those.

What you really want:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_base_of.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

class MsgContent {};

class RecipientList
{
public:
    template<class T>
    typename boost::enable_if<
        typename boost::is_base_of<MsgContent, T>::type
      , void>::type
    fillMessageWithRecipients(T* t) { }
};

class SomeMsg : public MsgContent {};

int main()
{
  RecipientList recipients;
  SomeMsg m;
  recipients.fillMessageWithRecipients( &m );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the `SomeMsg m` must be a pointer type, not reference :(

Comment: @RobertDailey In my example it is a pointer. Look at the `&`.

Comment: This definitely works, thanks; kind of embarrassing that I've forgotten how to use type traits :P

Answer (score 2):

You should use is_base_of toghether with [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html).

is_base_of itself is just predicate.

[live demo](http://ideone.com/KGnBia)

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base1 {};
struct Derived1 : Base1 {};

struct Base2 {};
struct Derived2 : Base2 {};

template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_base_of<Base1, T>, void >::type f(T* p)
{
    cout << "Base1" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if< boost::is_base_of<Base2, T>, void >::type f(T* p)
{
    cout << "Base2" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Derived1 d1;
    Derived2 d2;
    f(&d1);
    f(&d2);
}
```

Output is:

```
Base1
Base2
```